# Return Oracle column names in table.column format?

Tags: oracle

Is there any setting or method I can use to get Oracle to return results in `<table>.<column>` format?  For example:

Query:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       foo f
INNER JOIN bar b
ON         b.foo_id = f.id
```

Desired results:

```
F.ID  F.BLAH  B.ID  B.FOO_ID  B.BLAH
--------------------------------------------------------
1     blah    7     1         blah
2     blah    8     2         blah
3     blah    9     2         blah
```

The obvious solution is to individually alias each column `SELECT f.id AS F_ID, ...`; however, I'm needing to export some very large legacy tables (300+ columns), so using this method would cause the queries to be enormous and impractical.

Comment: İ'm not competent in PL/SQL, but perhaps you may try to rename columns of tables before joining them.

Comment: How are you exporting the data?  Maybe this logic belongs in that export tool, instead of the individual statements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no "option" in Oracle to do this; you *may* be able to find a client that allows you to do so as this is a job that would normally be done in the client; I don't know of one.

To expand upon [tbone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230772/458741) you're going to have to do this dynamically. This *does not* mean that you have to list every column. You would use the [data dictionary](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datadict.htm#CNCPT2140), specifically [all_tab_columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2103.htm#REFRN20277) or `user_tab_columns` to create your query. It would be easier to create a view with the exact definition you want so that you can re-use it if you want.

The aim is to use the fact that the columns existence is stored in a table as a string in order to create a query to use that column. As the column names and table names are stored as strings you can use string aggregation techniques to easily create a query or DDL statement that you can then manually, or dynamically, execute.

If you're using Oracle 11g Release 2 the [`listagg`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG8702) function is available to help you:

```
select 'create or replace view my_view as 
        select '
      || listagg( table_name || '.' || column_name 
               || ' as ' 
               || substr(table_name,1,1) || '_' 
               || column_name, ', ')
        within group 
         ( order by case when table_name = 'FOO' then 0 else 1 end
                  , column_id
          )
       || ' from foo f
            join bar b
              on f.id = b.foo_id'
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name in ('FOO','BAR')
        ;
```

Assuming this table structure:

```
create table foo ( id number, a number, b number, c number);
create table bar ( foo_id number, a number, b number, c number);
```

This single query produces the following:

```
create or replace view my_view as 
 select FOO.ID as F_ID, FOO.A as F_A, FOO.B as F_B, FOO.C as F_C
      , BAR.FOO_ID as B_FOO_ID, BAR.A as B_A, BAR.B as B_B, BAR.C as B_C 
   from foo f 
   join bar b on f.id = b.foo_id
```

and here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/362b3/3) to prove it.

In you're not using 11.2 you can achieve exactly the same results using the undocumented function [`wm_concat`](http://psoug.org/definition/WM_CONCAT.htm) or the user-defined function [`stragg`](http://www.oracle.com/splash/collabsuite/maintenance/index.html), which was created by Tom Kyte. Oracle Base has an article on [string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) and there are many posts on Stack Overflow.

As a little addendum you can actually create exactly what you're looking for with a small change to the above query. You can use a [quoted identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements008.htm) to create a column in the `TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME` format. You *have* to quote it as `.` is not a valid character for an object name in Oracle. The benefit of this is that you gain exactly what you want. The downside is that querying the created view is a huge pain if you don't use `select * from ...`; selecting named columns will *require* them to be quoted.

```
select 'create or replace view my_view as
        select '
      || listagg( table_name || '.' || column_name 
               || ' as ' 
               || '"' || table_name || '.'
               || column_name || '"', ', ')
        within group 
         ( order by case when table_name = 'FOO' then 0 else 1 end
                  , column_id
          )
       || ' from foo f
            join bar b
              on f.id = b.foo_id'
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name in ('FOO','BAR')
        ;
```

[This query returns](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/362b3/5):

```
create or replace view my_view as 
 select FOO.ID as "FOO.ID", FOO.A as "FOO.A", FOO.B as "FOO.B", FOO.C as "FOO.C"
      , BAR.FOO_ID as "BAR.FOO_ID", BAR.A as "BAR.A"
      , BAR.B as "BAR.B", BAR.C as "BAR.C"
   from foo f 
   join bar b on f.id = b.foo_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Using aliases wouldn't make the queries become impractical, its just not nearly as convenient as typing *.  Use dynamic SQL to generate the columns for you:

```
select 'f.' || column_name || ' as F_' || column_name || ','
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'FOO'
order by column_id;
```

Do the same for any other wide tables you need, and copy/paste into your query.  Also note the 30 char limit, hopefully none of your columns are over 28 in size.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I was specifically asking for a solution that does not involve explicitly listing the columns.